# Swift: Converting UIButton into UIBarButtonItem, does it really have to be this complicated?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have written an extension on `UIButton` which converts a `UIButton` into a `UIBarButtonItem`.

I tried to most simple solution using `init(customView` on `UIBarButtonItem` passing in my button, like this:

```
lazy var myButton: UIButton = { 
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    // setting up button here...
    return button
}()

let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)
```

But I had several constraints issues. Actually I did not only want to put one button, but three items in the navigation bar. So I tried putting my three buttons into a `UIStackView` and then set `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: stackView)` which works like a charm **on iOS 10**. But on **iOS 9** the position of the buttons did not work.

Anyway I resorted to using `UIBarButtonItem` instead of `UIButton`s, but I did not want to create `UIBarButton`s for iOS 9 but `UIButton`s for iOS 10. So I wrote an extension creating `UIBarButtonItem`s from `UIButton`s. Which enabled this code.

### Solution handling iOS 9 and iOS 10

```
func setupNavigationBar() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let stackView: UIStackView = [.views(buttons)] //syntax enabled by framework `ViewComposer`: github.com/Sajjon/ViewComposer
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: stackView)
    } else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons.reversed().flatMap { $0.barButtonItem } // syntax enabled by extension below
    }
}
```

Here is my code for my extension.

### Extension UIButton

```
extension UIButton {

    var barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem? {
        return barButtonItem()
    }

    func barButtonItem(
        style: UIBarButtonItemStyle = .plain,
        state: UIControlState = .normal,
        controlEvent: UIControlEvents = .primaryActionTriggered
        ) -> UIBarButtonItem? {

        guard
            let target = allTargets.first,
            let selectorName = actions(forTarget: target, forControlEvent: controlEvent)?.first,
            case let image = image(for: state), case let title = title(for: state),
            (image != nil || title != nil)
            else { return nil }

        let action = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName)

        if let image = image {
            return UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: style, target: target, action: action)
        }

        if let title = title {
            return UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: style, target: target, action: action)
        }

        return nil //should not happen
    }
}
```

#### Question 1: Why did positioning the UIButtons inside the UIStackView not work on iOS 9?

#### Question 2: Is my extension unnecessarily complex? Or insecure somehow?

Answer (score 14):

The extension can be simplified

```
extension UIButton {
    func toBarButtonItem() -> UIBarButtonItem? {
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once!